# What loop should I use?

Tags: java, loops

I am supposed to do a word-quiz game between two languages in Java, and I am not sure what type of loop should be used when controlling the input from the user! I have three "conditions/terms"

1. if the user types the right answer
2. if the user has some spelling mistake
3. if the user types `q` to quit the game

I was first thinking of using a for loop, but I don't seem to figure it out!

My code looks like this right now

```
public static int takeTest(ArrayList<Sweng> Wordlist) {
        int result = 0;
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < Wordlist.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(Wordlist.get(i).getSweWord());
            String answer = keyboardInput.nextLine();
        }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know how many times the loop need to be executed, you can use a `do-while` loop.

This loop first execute the code inside the `do` brackets, and then check the condition.

This is an implementation example:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;   // a variable to store the input
do {
    System.out.println(/*your question here*/);
    input = s.nextLine();
    // do something
} while(!input.equals("q"));    // exit the loop if 'input' equals "q"
```

Otherwise, you can do something like that, but it's a very bad and rough way to do this. I don't recommend you to use it.

Note: You'll need to adjust this code with your `ArrayList<Sweng> WordList`. It's just an example!

```
ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> possibleAnswers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();  // list of a list because we need a set of strings for every questions
ArrayList<String> correctAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
// init the lists

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int result = 0;
boolean quit = false;   // if true, then quit the for loop
for(int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) { // repeat 'questions.size()' times
    String answer = null;
    do {
        if(answer != null) System.out.println("This isn't a valid answer!");    // if 'answer' is null, don't show this output because it's the first time in the loop
        System.out.println(questions.get(i));
        answer = s.nextLine();
        if(answer.equals("q")) {    // if input is "q", set 'quit' to 'true' and break the do-while loop
            quit = true;
            break;
        }
    } while(!possibleAnswers.get(i).contains(answer));  // if the answer is a valid answer, quit the loop
    if(quit) break;     // if quit is true, break the for loop
    if(answer.equals(correctAnswers.get(i))) {  // check for correct answer
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        result++;
    } else System.out.println("Wrong!");
}
System.out.println("You scored " + result + "!");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you actually know how often you want to loop at max (max. the amount of questions inside your `wordList`, since it's a quiz), you can actually keep the `for` loop.

You could use a `while` or `do-while` loop here, but then you would need a seperate index variable to keep track of the current question, and this fact alone indicates that a `for` loop is more suitable here.

I modified your code snippet to change / add the following things:

- Variable names should start lowercase. So `Wordlist` -> `wordList`.
- Added conditions regarding verification of the answer and quitting.
- Added some print statements.

Example:

```java
public static int takeTest(ArrayList<Sweng> wordList) {
    int result = 0;
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(wordList.get(i).getSweWord());
        System.out.println("Please enter the answer:");
        String answer = keyboardInput.nextLine();
        if (wordList.get(i).getResultWord().equals(answer)) { // correct answer
            System.out.println("Correct answer!");
            result++;
        } else if ("q".equals(answer)) { // quitting
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
            break;
        } else { // incorrect answer
            System.out.println("Incorrect answer!");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Sidenote: Since I don't know the structure of your `Sweng` class, I called the method to retrieve the result word `getResultWord()`.